# No routes work on my Laravel Project

Tags: php, laravel, exception, nginx

routes.php:

```
<?php
use App\Task;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

Route::get('/test/', function () {
    return "Hello World";
});
```

nginx/sites-available/default:

```
...
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$query_string;
}
```

NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php (line 179)

Comment: Remove the slashes from your route: `Route::get('test', function(){ ... })`, especially if you're getting `local.domain/test`

Comment: Didn't work. Still getting NotFoundHttpException.

Comment: post all of your nginx configuration

Comment: @JDoes : How you get this error?